# C# why List.Remove() breaks 'for loop'?

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

i really have no idea why the for loop only loops once. i think the logic is correct, below is the code.

```
// the list is named 'dataList'

for(int i = 0 ; i < dataList.Count; i ++)
{
    string[] data = dataList[i].Split('+');
    string[] wsno = data[0].Split(':');
    if(wsno[1].Equals(tbWorkSheet.Text)) 
    {
        dataList.Remove(dataList[i])   <<<< remove string that has the same number
        //data removed
        //for loop ends up here idk why..
    }
}
```

dataList.Count will be the size of the list.

the case is like this.. 
i want to remove multiple strings stored in a list, each string has its group number. 
So, the for loop will loop until the last one. but when it found a string with the same number with the desired one, it will execute the if statement which is to remove it.

Comment: `dataList.Count` is what value specifically?

Comment: How many times are you expecting it to loop? Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: This is generally why you iterate in reverse when removing (i.e. from count-1 to 0)... it makes index management much easier.

Comment: @Arran dataList.Count is the list size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very bad idea. By removing values from your list like that you will jump over the next item in your list.

For example you have 3 items in your list at index 0, 1, 2.

First iteration: i = 0
You remove item at index 0. List now have items at index 0, 1 (fist item removed).

Second iteration: i = 1.
Notice here how the item located at index 1 is moved to 0. While our index counter goes to 1 from 0. So we will "skip" this item.

If you only have 2 items in your List he will break after the first remove. This because the count is decreased while your index is increased.

By going reverse order you will eliminate this problem.

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 2, 1 };
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    list.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Edit: As **Rawling** mentions you can go forward if you *decrease your counter* when you remove items.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    list.RemoveAt(i--);
}
```

Comment: This is the canonical way of doing it.

Comment: I'd consider going forwards and decrementing `i` when I remove something, but maybe only if it were important to be going through the list forwards.

Answer (score 3):

You can use List.RemoveAll generic method. Method removes from List all items matching the predicate.
Method signature is following:

int List.RemoveAll(Predicate match)

It returns the number of elements that were removed.

See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to decrement `i` after removing the item. This will skip the next item, since all subsequent items will have been renumbered down by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Loop backwards through the list:

```
for(int i = dataList.Count; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    string[] data = dataList[i].Split('+');
    string[] wsno = data[0].Split(':');
    if(wsno[1].Equals(tbWorkSheet.Text)) 
    {
        dataList.RemoveAt(dataList[i])   <<<< remove string that has the same number
        //data removed
        //for loop ends up here idk why..
    }
}
```

Comment: This may still cause issues if there are duplicate entries in the list - `Remove` may not remove the `i`th element. `RemoveAt` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer making a new list rather than modifying the original collection.

Can be done neatly with LINQ:

```
dataList =
    dataList
        .Select(x => new{
            dataItem = x,
            secondWsno = x.Split('+').First().Split(':').Skip(1).First()
        })
        .Where(x => !x.secondWsno.Equals(tbWorkSheet.Text))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Well if you have a list with a lot of items and you're only removing one or two, it's rather excessive to re-create the list just to remove a small percentage of items.  This is generally better when you're removing a significant percentage.

Comment: It's easy to overestimate the cost of such operations. I'd prefer to do it this way until I saw it to be problematic, but yes, in the case of minor removal it might be overkill.

Answer (score -5):

You cannot change the list in a for loop.
You can hold the data you want to remove in another list and then remove it after you exit the loop.

Comment: You can. You can't in a foreach loop.